# Windows development on a Mac Pro

Tags: android, macos, windows-7

Looking to do iphone, android, and possibly windows phone development on a Mac Pro.  What are the pluses and minuses of using a Mac Pro and a dual boot.  Unlike most, Windows 7 will be the primary OS since most supporting software will be done with Visual Studio 08/10 over the next year.  I have found driver issues from a few years ago.  Do any of these issues still exist?

Answer (score 2):

The BootCamp drivers on the OSX (Snow) Leopard should cover everything.  Although, they most likely will need to be updated.

Personally, I prefer [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com) so I can run Windows 7 and OS X simultaneously.